# Issues upgrading SonarQube 6.4 to 6.7 LTS

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Trying to upgrade the my sonarqube instance running on an m3.xlarge Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03.1.20170617 x86_64 HVM GP2

Walking through upgrade instructions here https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading

But when I go to startup sonar in the new directory it comes up for just a few seconds then shuts down. Is anyone else having this issue or am I missing something in the instructions? Updated the sonar.properties file with the same info as in my 6.4 version and I did not see any changes that needed to be made in the wrapper.conf. The older version still comes up fine.

Wondering if this has to do with:
a) Trying to connect to the existing DB
b) Not having installed any plugins yet

```
/etc/sonarqube-6.7/bin/linux-x86-64
[root@ip linux-x86-64]# ./sonar.sh start
Starting SonarQube...
Started SonarQube.
[root@ip-linux-x86-64]# ls -la
total 144
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Nov 27 21:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root   4096 Nov  7 15:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Nov  7 15:16 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      6 Nov 27 21:08 SonarQube.pid
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  15522 Nov  7 15:06 sonar.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 111027 Nov  7 15:06 wrapper
[root@ip- linux-x86-64]# ls -la
total 144
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Nov 27 21:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root   4096 Nov  7 15:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Nov  7 15:16 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      6 Nov 27 21:08 SonarQube.pid
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  15522 Nov  7 15:06 sonar.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 111027 Nov  7 15:06 wrapper
[root@ip- linux-x86-64]# ls -la
total 140
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Nov 27 21:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root   4096 Nov  7 15:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Nov  7 15:16 lib
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  15522 Nov  7 15:06 sonar.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 111027 Nov  7 15:06 wrapper
[root@ linux-x86-64]# ls -la
total 140
```

### sonar.log

```
vi sonar.log 

--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2017.11.27 21:20:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /etc/sonarqube-6.7/temp
2017.11.27 21:20:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2017.11.27 21:20:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/etc/sonarqube-6.7/elasticsearch]: /etc/sonarqube-6.7/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=/etc/sonarqube-6.7/temp/conf/es
2017.11.27 21:20:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2017.11.27 21:20:50 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2017.11.27 21:20:50 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2017.11.27 21:20:51 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2017.11.27 21:20:51 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
  2017.11.27 21:20:51 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

### es.log

```
 vi es.log 

2017.11.27 21:20:51 ERROR es[][o.e.b.Bootstrap] Exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:106) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:195) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:342) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:132) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:123) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:70) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:134) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
2017.11.27 21:20:51 WARN  es[][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:123) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:70) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:134) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:106) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:195) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:342) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:132) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version SonarQube 6.7 uses a new version of the ElasticSearch engine. For security reasons that engine prohibits running as root. So you need an other user on you system with rights to read/write in the sonarqube (sub)directories and
the temporary directories it uses.

Comment: Makes sense. Will try and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Also note that when it finally did come up that it hd the maintenance page and had to look at the sonar.log to see this message :Database must be upgraded. Please backup database and browse /setup

Which was simple enough to just go to <sonarurl>:9000/setup and click the button

Comment: @isaacweathers See also [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading) upgrade page. For future upgrades. Please always make a backup before upgrading.

Comment: That's the one I was following. Did not mention not being ROOT when you unzip and install but guess that is a good practice. Did make a backup and backup of the DB. Well, snaphshots via AWS.